# Missing Audit Logs in Keycloak

Tags: logging, keycloak, keycloak-services

[image]

Even after enabling the save events settings in the config tab of Keylcloak admin GUI. I am not able to see any logs inside login events.

[image]

Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Actually that's the only thing you have to do. Which version of keycloak you are on. Did you modify the standalone by any chance.

Audits logs are realm wise. If you have configured it for REALM A, then if you are accessing any client that is registered in REALM A will generate the logs. You might be login onto MASTER realm and checking the audit logs in someother realm.

Can you also try setting some value in the expiration tab and save.
Also did you try any login/logout/incorrect login after saving this.

Follow this guide to double check your settings.
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/server_admin/topics/events/login.html